# AutoIt: Get text from inside a Windows Metro app

Tags: windows, modern-ui, autoit

I'm automating a Windows Metro app and need to read some text that it returns. I've tried using the "AutoIt v3 Window Info" utility to inspect the application but it's unable to see the text. What other methods can I use to achieve this.